# To prove that $F^n = W \oplus \text{span} (e_i \mid i \in S)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $W \subseteq F^n$ be a subspace of dimension $K$. Show that there is a set $S \subseteq \{1,2,3,\ldots,n\}$ of cardinality $|S| = n-k$ such that
$$F^n = W \oplus \operatorname{span} (e_i \mid i \in S)$$

My idea is that
$(e_i\mid i=1,2,\ldots,n)$ is a standard basis of $F^n$. Since $S \subseteq F^n$ of dimension $k$. There would be exactly $k$  $e_i$'s which span $S$.

Please tell me how can I write a formal proof. Maybe I can use replacement theorem or something else.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is not correct. For example in $\mathbb R^2$, none of $e_1,e_2$ spans $\mathbb R(e_1+e_2)$.

However, you can proceed by induction. If $W \neq F^n$, one of the $\mathbb Re_i$, say $e_j$ is not included in $W$ (why?).

So $W \oplus \mathbb Re_j$ contains strictly $W$. Follow on that way until you reach out $F^n$.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I don't have any clue how to solve this problem.

Comment: I updated the answer with hints for a proof.

Comment: At least one $e_{j}$ is not included in $W$ because if it were then $W=F^{n}$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: Can you tell me how can I proceed after this, and on what should I use induction$?$

Comment: On dimension of linear subspaces including $W$ until you reach out $F^n$.